# libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException without the regular error message

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, xcode8

My application is crashing with the error above. I've checked all my connections between the swift file and the storyboard, and nothing seems to be wrong. Furthermore, the debugger doesn't seem to be printing an error message. This is what it gives me:

```
2016-06-19 16:49:33.549062 Food[20053:3251540] [LogFacilityCK] Operation 8A5BA319FDEBBCBA finished
2016-06-19 16:49:33.549097 Food[20053:3251542] [] nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [1 api.parse.com:443 ready resolver (satisfied)]
2016-06-19 16:49:33.549975 Food[20053:3251542] [] nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [1.1 52.72.144.232:443 ready socket-flow (satisfied)]
2016-06-19 16:49:33.550439 Food[20053:3251540] [LogFacilityOP] Finished operation <CKQueryOperation: 0x7f8a64ea80d0; operationID=8A5BA319FDEBBCBA,  stateFlags=finished, metrics=<CKOperationMetrics: 0x7f8a64ea61b0; cloudKitMetrics=<CKMetric: 0x7f8a64ea77b0; startDate=2016-06-19 08:49:03 +0000, duration=0.413, queueing=0.073, executing=1.108, bytesUploaded=369, bytesDownloaded=436, connections=1, connectionsCreated=0>>, requestIDs=(F13449B5-44D2-418F-8E68-8142C07DD8DB)>
2016-06-19 16:49:33.550856 Food[20053:3251542] [] __nw_socket_service_writes_block_invoke sendmsg(fd 9, 31 bytes): socket has been closed
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

The line that is highlighted upon crashing can be found in the link below (took a screenshot of the entire screen just in case, I'm not sure if this is of any use):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AukG.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you throw an exception and no one catches the exception. Objective C and C++ exceptions use the same mechanism for exceptions. Try setting an exception breakpoint to catch exceptions as they are being thrown. This will show you who threw the exception that isn't being caught.[image]